# Array considered to be a pointer in the arguments

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program where the user inserts the price of a certain item of his choice, then that price is stored in a list, and the user can expand that last as he wishes, but there is a problem, even though I have the exact same arguments and parameters, the array "prices" is considered to be a pointer for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ask(char ques, int index, double prices[index], double price)
{
    printf("Do you want to expand your list y/n: ");
    scanf("%c", &ques);

    printf("What do you want the price of the next item to be: ");
    scanf("%lf", &price);

    switch (ques)
    {
    case 'y':
        prices[index + 1] = price;
    case 'n':
        main();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int index = -1;
    double prices[index];
    double price;
    char ques;

    ask(ques, index, prices[index], price);
}
```

I have this error: argument of type "double" is incompatible with parameter of type "double *"C

Comment: `ask(ques, index, prices[index], price);` -> `ask(ques, index, prices, price);`. That will fix the error message but you have other problems as well.

Comment: You cannot define an array of size `-1` (like you tried to do when declaring `prices` in `main()`).

Comment: There's a lot more errors once you actually fix that typo, such as `int index = -1; double price[index];` - what's an array with negative size supposed to be?

Comment: `int index = -1; double prices[index]` That won't work. `index` needs to be the final max required num elements of the array. Static arrays do not automatically grow in C. If you want to a growable array you need to dynamically allocate using `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: @SomethingSomething you can declare arrays with non-constant sizes in C99. And `const int` is not a constant expression for the purpose of array size, so your "non-const variable" claim is misleading

Comment: You need to pass `index` into the function so it knows which element to store into. Or you need to change the function to take a pointer to a single element and not the whole array as you have it now.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, currently, your array cannot be extended, since it is fully allocated on the stack, such that it is physically surrounded by other local variables and cannot grow. So as others mentioned, you should either leave it local (on the stack), but then declare it with the maximal size you might need, or switch to using a pointer to an array that will be dynamically allocated on the heap (using malloc, realloc, etc.).

Comment: @UnholySheep fixed my comment.

Comment: An array *decays* to a pointer when passed to a function, and the argument `double prices[index]` defines a pointer, also being equivalent to `double prices[]`.

Comment: "Considered to be a pointer for some reason".  Because that is how the language works: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

A solution using an array on the stack to store the prices.

*prices.c*

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void ask(double prices[], int *elements, int max_elements)
{
    if (*elements >= max_elements) {
        printf("List is already full. (%d elements)\n", *elements);
        return;
    }

    while (*elements < max_elements) // as long as there is space left
    {
        double price;
        printf("What do you want the price of the next item to be: ");
        scanf("%lf", &price);

        prices[*elements] = price; // store price in array
        *elements += 1; // increase number of elements

        if (*elements == max_elements) {
            printf("List is full. (%d elements)\n", max_elements);
            break; // leave loop
        }

        char ques;
        printf("Do you want to expand your list (y/n): ");
        scanf(" %c", &ques);
        if (ques == 'n') {
            break; // leave loop
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int MAX_ELEMENTS = 10000;  // 10000 prices should be enough for now
    double prices[MAX_ELEMENTS]; // array to store 10000 prices
    int elements = 0; // number of prices, currently none

    ask(prices, &elements, MAX_ELEMENTS); // let user fill it

    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        printf("%3d: %.2lf\n", i + 1, prices[i]); // print price number and price 
    }

    return 0; // return 0 to indicate no error
}
```

Let's see how it works so far:

```
$ gcc -Wall prices.c
$ ./a.out           
What do you want the price of the next item to be: 1.11
Do you want to expand your list (y/n): y
What do you want the price of the next item to be: 2.22
Do you want to expand your list (y/n): y
What do you want the price of the next item to be: 101
Do you want to expand your list (y/n): y
What do you want the price of the next item to be: 1000000.99
Do you want to expand your list (y/n): n
  1: 1.11
  2: 2.22
  3: 101.00
  4: 1000000.99
$
```

Test it online: https://onlinegdb.com/x1jVUU6GT